# Will the EEA directives still apply in the UK after Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, family, brexit

I am a German citizen working in the UK and I'd like my non-EEA mother (who is dependent on my financial help) to apply for the EEA family permit. But I am afraid we won't have time to do the paperwork before Brexit.

Does the following quote from https://www.gov.uk/family-permit mean she could apply after Brexit?

> There will be no change to the rights and status of EU citizens currently living in the UK until 30 June 2021, or 31 December 2020 if the UK leaves the EU without a deal.

Just to clarify:

- I am already in the UK;
- My mother is *not* in the UK and would apply for the family permit from outside the UK.

Answer (score 1):

EEA nationals and their family members who travel to the UK and take up residence before the end of the transition period will be allowed to remain with “pre-settled status”. If they then stay for a continuous period of five years, they will become eligible for permanent residence (settled status under the new provisions).

An EEA citizen continuously resident in the UK before 31 December 2020 will be able to be joined after that date by close family members who are resident overseas if the relationship existed at that date and it continues to exist when the person wishes to come to the UK.
https://www.rlegal.com/news/what-the-brexit-withdrawal-agreement-means-for-europeans-immigration-repercussions/

Comment: But in case of no-deal Brexit, the passages you quoted don't apply, right?